# Как узнать на сколько нужно подвинутся при определенном угле

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр

У меня есть персонаж он двигается под углом 30 градусов но вот незадача: под углом например 90 градусов понятно он будет изменять `y` на 1, под углом 45 `x` и `y` на 1, но насколько нужно изменить если персонаж под углом например 30 градусов?

Comment: А вы уверены, что под 45 это x=1 y=1, клетка по диагонали все таки больше, чем ее стороны ?  Или вы решили этим пренебречь ? Если бы нужно было бы точно, ни чем не пренебрегая, то у вас были бы косинус и синус угла

Comment: Покажите пример пожалуйста

Comment: Пример чего ? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5  радиус (он же  гипотенуза) у вас равен 1. вам надо получить два катета  P.S. только если угол в градуcах, не забудьте перевести его в радианы

Comment: В каком классе проходят синусы и косинусы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основы геометрии:

x = cos(a) * L

y = sin(a) * L

Где а - угол, L - длина пути.